# How can i create local Notification in worklight

Tags: notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm creating an app using Worklight. I need to show a Notification at specific time like an alarm clock. It'd work when offline so i cannot use Push Notification.

I need Notification like image below. Thanks.

[image: Notification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS's [Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) feature does not have built-in support in Worklight.

One way to add Local Notifications support is by extending your application [using a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova), which will allow you to run Native code.
This means that you will natively implement it by following Apple's APIs: to schedule the notification in the app and to then receive a notification locally via the OS, that will in turn allow you to open the app and execute an optional callback, etc...

You could either write a [custom Cordova plug-in of your own](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova),
Or [find existing plug-ins on the web](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cordova%20ios%20local%20notifications&safe=off).

- When adding an existing Cordova plug-in to Worklight (depending on your version of Worklight and version of Cordova), the instructions to do so are a bit different at this time.
- This video demonstrates one instance of how to do add an existing Cordova plug-in: [Integrating Cordova plugins into Worklight applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woaioPzyKiQ)

Comment: I tried using this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications it show local notification but all event won't fired. in javascript it show "require is not defined" and "module is not defined"

Comment: You'll need to better explain what you've done... If you want, provide the worklight project.

Comment: @SquallLeonhart, see my implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077230/using-katzer-local-notification-in-ibm-worklight