# Using katzer local notification in IBM Worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I want to use this cordova plugin at https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

How to go about integrating this plugin with my existing IBM Worklight project? I have trying various methods to integrate it without any result.

I am getting this error currently from the logcat:

```
02-24 11:15:03.035: D/CordovaLog(2439): file:///data/data/com.iCareApp/files/www/default/index.html: Line 17 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notification' of undefined
```

Or is there any other easier alternatives to get this done? Basically i want to be able to schedule local notification on the device at specific times from the data stored in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by following the below.

Demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/58urdluauc8u3l1/AndroidLocalNotifications.zip

Because Worklight does not support Cordova's Plugman to easily "install" Cordova v3 plug-ins, some manual labor is required to get it all set-up properly... blachs.

Note the appName , it is used throughout the process for plug-in declarations. If you use a different name for in your app, you will need to update the values accordingly with yours.

1. Pay attention to the `nativeResources` folder, where I've placed the files I edited:

   - AndroidManifest.xml:

     - In it I added the required permission, receivers, activities
   - libs folder:

     - Contains required .jar file by the plug-in
   - src folder:

     - Contains the plug-in's Java classes
     - In them I've edited the plug-in import declaration
   - res\xml folder:

     - Contains config.xml; see at the bottom for the plug-in feature declaration
2. In index.html:

   - The plug-in's JavaScript implementation is referenced in the `head` element
     `<script src="js/local-notification.js"></script>`
3. In main.js:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit(){
       window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'this is a local notification' });
   }
   ```

   The above will send a local notification immediately after the application's launch.
   [In the plug-in's homepage](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) you can read more about the possible notification options.
4. In local-notification.js:

   - Add at the top:
     `cordova.define("LocalNotification", function(require, exports, module) {`
   - Add at the bottom:
     `});`
5. In the generated Android project\assets\www\default\js\worklight\cordova_plugins.js, add:

   ```
   ,
   {
       "file": "../js/local-notification.js",
       "id": "LocalNotification",
       "clobbers": [
           "plugin.notification.local"
       ] 
   }
   ```

   Note that re-building the Worklight project will **overwrite** this file, and thus your changes in it will be gone... you'll need to repeat this step after every build.

   There is no good way that I could find to preserve changes to this file between Worklight Studio builds.

[image]

Comment: I got it working in a similar way after few trial and errors. Thanks for the answer. How do i set notification for a particular time. How do i set date object with time say 11.30 PM ?

Comment: I didn't try all options, but check the plug-in website - the documentation they provide is very clear. If you have additional questions that are pertinent to the PLUG-IN, please contact its author - there is an email in the plug-in website.