# custom plugin installation procedure in worklight6.0

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Few days back i started working on ibm worklight platformVersion="6.1.0.01.20140427-1450".
But i am facing some problem regarding custom plugin. For adding native functionality to hybrid application with apache cordova plugin in IOS I found the following link
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_03_iOS_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf
I tried this but everytime on compilation i got "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".

So my question is that after cordova 2.9 ,it stopped adding classes and files manually. So we do the same by installing the command line. But i tried the same thing in worklight based project then it gives error that it is not a cordova based project.

So i think that we can't install the plugin into worklight project with the help of command line thats why its giving the linker error.
Please try to solve my problem by proving me the solution.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error you've mentioned as-is is meaningless, you should add the full error.

Regardless,
Worklight currently does not support Cordova 3's Plugman, so you cannot easily "install" plug-ins.

As a way to show how this can be done, you can follow the guidelines provided for this question: [Using katzer local notification in IBM Worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077230/using-katzer-local-notification-in-ibm-worklight/24081760#24081760)

The solution provided in the above question shows a "step-by-step" of how to add existing Cordova 3 plug-ins to a Worklight application, for Android.

It is the same for iOS with one exception. in iOS you must reference the plug-in's .m and .h files in Xcode's Classes folder (right-click and select "Add files...")

Comment: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am getting this error every time.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything if you don't explain what you're done. Please follow the instructions in my answer.

Comment: I followed your guidance but problem comes where i create a class in xcode and we use callback for custom plugin because callback id property is defined in the CDVInvokedUrlCommand class of cordova library. The custom class I make in worklight project that is not able to access the properties of cordova library and every time i get the following error : 
 "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" 
Is this explanation enough ??

Comment: Putting the Class file in the Classes folder will not reference it automatically - you must do this in Xcode by selecting "Add files...". This is the only way for the project to recognize your Codova plug-in (class files).

Comment: I created class file in XCode. I did not copy paste.

Comment: Then I don't know what you're doing. Provide a demo Worklight project and rquired files to test.