# IBM MobileFirst Studio 7.0 Local notification

Tags: cordova-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to use local notification in IBm mobilefirst studio 7.0 
tried the plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications and  worklight project 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/58urdluauc8u3l1/AndroidLocalNotifications.zip

unfortunately both are not working

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think you should have mentioned *where* you got that project/.zip from?

That project was implemented by me, and it is fully explained here: [Using katzer local notification in IBM Worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077230/using-katzer-local-notification-in-ibm-worklight)

You need to follow the instructions.
You need to also google a bit: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

Comment: I tried all the methods that you were mentioned , but the project is not working in Worklight version 7.0