# Cordova local notification is not working in worklight 7.0

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, localnotification

I wanted to integrate local notification in worklight. So i used https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications plugin for local notification.

When i try to integrate with worklight its not working. I followed steps mentioned in this [Using katzer local notification in IBM Worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077230/using-katzer-local-notification-in-ibm-worklight). But still its not working.

getting error [image]

I am getting sClass not found.

Answer (score 0):

I followed my instructions in the question you've linked to - simply created a new project and copied over all the resources, and it worked for me in the Android Emulator.

Here is a the same thing, in MobileFirst Platform Foundation **7.1** (you cannot import it in **7.0**, but you can just follow the same steps...).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wfu9rytsivvxcrb/LocalNotifications71.zip?dl=0