# How do i set local notification for a particular time?

Tags: javascript, cordova, localnotification

I am using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077230/using-katzer-local-notification-in-ibm-worklight) in my app and managed to get the basic local notifications working on app start. Currently I'm trying to schedule a local notification after 5 seconds using this function from [katzer scheduling](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling). However, the function don't seems to work. I'm not quite sure where is the problem over here.

```js
scheduleDelayed = function () {
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
    _5_sec_from_now = new Date(now + 5 * 1000);

    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Scheduled with delay',
        text: 'Test Message 1',
        at: _5_sec_from_now,
        badge: 12
    });
};
```

Comment: yep. I've. The best plugin for local-notification. +1 for [katzer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

Comment: @user4706148 Are you facing any problem using it or seeking suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Sorry, I am pretty new to stack overflow, I've restated my question. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and errors, here's my findings. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077230/using-katzer-local-notification-in-ibm-worklight) defines certain attributes differently from [katzer's scheduling](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling). In this case, the 'at' attribute is defined as 'date' and 'text' is defined as 'message' in local-notification.js. Besides, the plugin is defined as 'add' instead of 'schedule', while the plugin is called by 'window.plugin.notification......' instead of 'cordova.plugins.notification......'.

This is the working code.

```js
scheduleDelayed = function () {
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
    _5_sec_from_now = new Date(now + 5 * 1000);
    alert(_5_sec_from_now);

    window.plugin.notification.local.add({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Scheduled with delay',
      message: 'Test Message 1',
      date: _5_sec_from_now
    });
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="scheduleDelayed()">In 5 sec</button>
</div>
```